# Splash Screen Not worked second time only

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen, activity-lifecycle

Please read carefully...
Here is my code for splash screen and backbutton Pressed.. All worked fine except  when i exit **first time** from app,after then splash screen not appeared but after first time, every time splash screen appreared when i click on app icon. Why splash screen not appeared after first time exit ?? if any confusion about question plz ask me..

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;


    public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
        // Splash screen timer
        private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                /*
                 * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
                 * want to show case your app logo / company
                 */

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                    // Start your app main activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // close this activity
                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
        //handle back button press
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
          //  mIsBackButtonPressed = true;
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();
            finish();

        }
  }



      // for back button

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
           // mIsBackButtonPressed = true;
           // super.onBackPressed();
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit Application?");
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    // Write your code here to execute after dialog


                                    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

                                    startActivity(startMain);
                                    finish();
                                    UploadActivity.isQuit = true;



                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ThanK U...",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })

                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        public static boolean isQuit = false
```

Manifest file

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.mypackage_name">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_nirvan"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:allowClearUserData="true"
            >

            <!--
                We will launch BaseActivity as launcher.
                We will check if BaseActivity launch first time and open desired activity and set navigation item selected
            -->

            <activity
                android:name=".SplashScreen"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".Login"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".UploadActivity" />
           <activity android:name=".SearchPeople" />
            <activity android:name=".InviteFriends" />
            <activity android:name=".ContactUs" />

            <activity
                android:name=".Details"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_details" />

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Login Activity

```
package com.mypkg;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

//import com.enventpc_03.nav11.com.R;
//import com.enventpc_03.nav11.SecondTab;

public class Login extends BaseActivity {

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;

    ArrayList<String> arealist;
    //ArrayList<GetterSetter> area;

    // Animation
    Animation animTogether;
    ImageView imageView1;

    // flag for Internet connection status
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

    // Connection detector class
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    //private Spinner spin1;


    EditText editText_name, editText_MobNo, editText_email;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //handle the local database
        loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();




        // //////////////initializing variables for shortcut on home during
        // installation//
        Context mContext = Login.this;
        SharedPreferences appPreferences;
        boolean isAppInstalled = false;
        // ----Shared pref. for shortcut on home during installation
        // starts------//
        appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        isAppInstalled = appPreferences.getBoolean("isAppInstalled", false);



        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isAppInstalled", true);
        editor.commit();


        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();


        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_register);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

                // get Internet status
                isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();




                EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_enter_name);
                EditText mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mobNo);
                EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);

                //loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(user, mobile, email);


                // Check The Validity of empty fields
                boolean Resp = validate(new EditText[]{user});

                // Check The Validity of emailID
                //  boolean e_valid = isEmailValid(email.getText());

                // Check The Validity of Mobile Numbers
                boolean mobile_valid = isMobValid(mobile.getText());

                if (Resp && mobile_valid) {

                    PostJson();
                } else {
//                  Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Field incorrect..!!!",
//                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (Resp) {
                    String pass = mobile.getText().toString();
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass) || pass.length() < 10) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                                "Mobile number should be of 10 digits..",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }// Chk Validation of mobile number

                    if (mobile_valid) {
                        if (isInternetPresent) {

                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Connecting....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Unable to connect the server, please check your data settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



            public boolean isMobValid(Editable mobile) {

                boolean isOk = false;

                String exp = "^[0-9]{10}$";
                CharSequence inputStr = mobile;

                Pattern pattern = Pattern
                        .compile(exp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    isOk = true;
                }
                return isOk;
            }

            public boolean validate(EditText[] fields) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                    EditText currentField = fields[i];
                    if (currentField.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {

                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Enter all the fields..!!!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    // ==========//

    // Function to display simple Alert Dialog- success/failure (used to set
    // icon)
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
                                Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting alert dialog icon
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    // ==================================================================================================================//

    // == To Pupolate the City/Zone Spinner ==//

    // ================= Populatin City/Zone Spinner Ends=======//



    // =========================== Json Object==================//

    public void PostJson() {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

        EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_enter_name);
        EditText mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mobNo);
        EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);

        //spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        //Local database
        editText_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_enter_name);
        editText_MobNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mobNo);
        editText_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        final String source = "Android";
        final String user_name = user.getText().toString();
        final String mobile_no = mobile.getText().toString();
        final String email_id = email.getText().toString();
        String indate = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        Toast.makeText(this, indate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //final String area = spin1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        params.put("source", source); // /parameters need to post.
        params.put("user", user_name); // /parameters need to post.
        params.put("email_id", email_id); // /parameters need to post.
        params.put("mobile", mobile_no); // /parameters need to post.
        params.put("indate", indate);
        //  params.put("area", area); // /parameters need to post.

//
//        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);

        String Url = "myurl/user_login/index.php";
        client.get(Url, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                System.out.println("Starting request");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    String mesaage = response.getString("message");
                    String success = response.getString("success");
                    String user_id = response.getString("user_id");

                    if (success.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, mesaage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, mesaage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                        // if email and mb is valid than login

                        Intent i1 = new Intent(Login.this, UploadActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i1);
                        finish();
                       //local database
                        String userName = editText_name.getText().toString();
                        String mob = editText_MobNo.getText().toString();
                        String email = editText_email.getText().toString();
                        loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, mob, email);



                        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        // save in cache memory
                        editor.putString("MOB", mobile_no);
                        editor.commit();



                        /*
                         * Intent i1 = new Intent(Login.this, Splash.class);
                         * startActivity(i1); finish();
                         */
                        // //////// { onFinish body}///////////////////////////////

                        Log.e("FINISHED_LOG", "onFinish request");

                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                                Login.PREFS_NAME, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = settings.edit();

                        // Set "hasLoggedIn" to true
                        editor1.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", true);

                        // Commit the edits!
                        editor1.commit();

                        // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {


                Log.e("ERROR_LOG", "onFailure request" + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error in Connection.....",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // //////// { onFinish body}///////////////////////////////
                    super.onFinish();


                // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            }
        });
    }

    // ==========================Re-Start/Ending of
    // project=============================================//
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();

        finish();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Login.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        boolean hasLoggedIn = settings.getBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);
        if (hasLoggedIn) {
            // Go directly to main activity
            Intent i1 = new Intent(Login.this, SplashScreen.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            finish();
        }

    }

    // ==========================Re-Start/Ending of
    // project=============================================//

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Login.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        // Get "hasLoggedIn" value. If the value doesn't exist yet false is
        // returned
        boolean hasLoggedIn = settings.getBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);

        if (hasLoggedIn) {
            // Go directly to main activity
            Intent i1 = new Intent(Login.this, UploadActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            finish();
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: add a "return" after alertDialog.show() ...and y is onBackPressed empty in SplashScreen activity?

Comment: It may bcz of you are overriding  Home button behavior in side onBackPressed()

Comment: Can you share your Manifest file. Also you have used finish() in onPause().please do check that because whenever app goes away from visibility ,splashactivity is destroyed. Maybe it is causing unwanted behavior.

Comment: Because it just return parent properties @Loknath

Comment: then What should i Do? @saeed.

Comment: Not Worked@Lokanath  using return

Comment: I have already check all activity life cycle as my knowledge@Manchem

Comment: post your login activity.java

Comment: Plz see above , I have post my login activity..

Answer (score 0):

This  should be your splash screen

```
   public class SplashScreen extends Activity { 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);

    Thread thread=new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try {
                sleep(3*1000);
                Intent intent=new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();

}}
```

//Android Manifest  //Intent Fileter (MAIN and LAUNCH both inside .Splash)

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="###############33"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Well,that's strange,should not have happened!!

Comment: All thing worked fine.. only after first time when i exit from my app ..then I start the app, Splash screen not appear .. After this when I exit from app and start many times app ..each time splash screen appeared and worked  fine.